# I want to split a long HTML table row into multiple rows according to the page width

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJS to generate a row of Material buttons in an HTML table. The selected button is highlighted.

```
<tr>
    <td ng-click="pbmain.selectWC(WC.WCName)" ng-repeat="WC in pbmain.WCList">
        md-button(ng-class="WC.WCName == pbmain.selectedWCName ? 'md-raised md-primary' : 'md-raised'") {{WC.WCName}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

The number of buttons and text on the buttons can be quite long and the row is often 2-3 times the width of the browser window. For the moment, I scroll across but I am looking for a more user-friendly solution.

[image: What I have]

I would like to be able to split the row automatically, according to the page width - something like the example below.

[image: The sort of thing I want]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by applying proper CSS to `table` and `button` elements. No need to split a row into multiple rows.

Example:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span><span>TEST</span>
    </td>       
</tr>
```

CSS

```
table { 
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: 100%
}

span {
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin: 10px;
   width: 100px;   
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pnrygjp/).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to accomplish this easily within a table. Maybe you could make some pre-work on your array to make it two-dimensional and then `ng-repeat` `tr` and `td` tags as well.

My solution would be a [clean grid system with Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

With this you can achieve a fully responsive screen. If you do not need to stick with a table system, then you should consider this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was searching by splitting rows into multiple rows and I got here.

It seems that your problem could be better solver by using `display: inline-block;` for every button.

However, if you really need a table for other purpose check at [this next approach](http://jsfiddle.net/rg0dk576/).
It would redrawn your linear tabular long table into a multilined table by only using css.
Than you can play around with your screen size.